# threading searching by different numbers

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, dataframe, selenium-webdriver

Friends, I'm new to python and I would like to do a task that is taking time. I need to search several numbers and scrape some information. I was researching threading to speed up the process.so far i've done it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from threading import Thread
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pandas as pd

def func(number):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
    driver.get(url)
    dados = pd.read_excel("TABLE (TRF).xlsx")
    dados.dropna(inplace=True)
    df = dados['email', 'pass']
    for row in df.itertuples():
        driver.find_element_by_id("84878").send_keys(row[1])
        b = driver.find_element_by_id("serch")
        b.click()
        inf = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="barraSuperiorPrincipal"]').text()
        with open(result.txt, "a") as arquivo:
            arquivo.write("%s %s\n" % (str(row[1]), inf))
# ---

    
url = 'https://www.test.com/'

number_of_threads = 5

#buttons = [False * number_of_threads] # create place
buttons = []

threads = []

for number in range(number_of_threads):
    t = Thread(target=func, args=(number,)) # get number for place in list `buttons`
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)
    buttons.append(False) # create place

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

But don't see, I use an excel with all the numbers to look up, how can I make each thread look up a number from the table? in my code all threads are searching for the same number

Comment: Use modulo operator `%`. First use "enumerate" to retrieve a count number for each row. Check if count modulo number of threads is equal to the thread number the "func" received as parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . Could you explain better? or if possible example with code? I didn't understand@MichaelButscher

Comment: Have you read in the documentation what "enumerate" does? And what the modulo operator does (for numbers; for a string it does something very different)? Have you played around a bit with these things in an interactive Python shell to understand it?

Comment: Your `func(number)` function does not use the `number` argument anywhere in it's body. That's probably not what you wanted.

Comment: Your `func(number)` function calls `ChromeDriverManager().install()` in _every thread._ I don't know how selenium works. I don't know whether `install` is something that needs to happen in each thread, but the name suggests that maybe it should only happen just one time.